# How Can I Skip a row(an iteration) in MSSQL Cursor based on some condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

How Can I Skip a row(an iteration) in MSSQL Cursor based on some condition, I have a DTS which migrates thousands of records and based on some criteria, some records need not be migrated as they are duplicates and want to skip these records.

Any idea how I can accomplish this in MSSQL Cursor?

Answer (score 4):

I guess the simplest way is to write IF statement inside the cursor. If the condition will be false you will skip records.

```
 DECLARE @ID INT
 DECLARE Curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
 DECLARE @Cnt INT

 CREATE TABLE ##Duplicates (ID INT, CarColor VARCHAR (50) )

 FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT  CarID
        FROM    dbo.CarPark
        WHERE   CarColour <> 'red'
        ORDER BY CarID

    OPEN Curs

        FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ID

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN

             INSERT INTO  ##Duplicates
             SELECT CarID, CarColor
             FROM  dbo.CarPark          
             WHERE ID = @ID;

             SET @Cnt = (SELECT Count(*) FROM ##Duplicates WHERE ID = @ID) ;

             IF @Cnt < 2 
             THEN /* Migrate */
             ELSE PRINT 'Duplicate'
             END

        FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ID 

        END

    CLOSE Curs
    DEALLOCATE Curs;
```

Answer (score 4):

I know that it I am too late to answer this question but for future seekers.. I believe the correct way to handle this is described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

your code is using a WHILE Loop (WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

To properly exit a while loop you use the BREAK key word

To skip an iteration in your loop you use the CONTINUE keyword

FROM MSDN:

BREAK
Causes an exit from the innermost WHILE loop. Any statements that appear after the END keyword, marking the end of the loop, are executed.

CONTINUE
Causes the WHILE loop to restart, ignoring any statements after the CONTINUE keyword.

EXAMPLE:
    -- AFTER declaring and opening a cursor...

```
FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ID    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN 
-- do something
IF [condition to skip record] 
CONTINUE            

FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ID 
  END
```

Comment: Best answer so far!

Comment: Beware! It is and infinite loop since you're skipping records without fetching the next one. You have to fetch the next record and then CONTINUE (all inside the IF statement).

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a few assumptions here but you could use the following as a guide:

```
    -- create some test data        
    SELECT '                                  ' [Word] INTO #MyTempDataset;
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'This';
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'is';
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'a';
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'basic';
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'basic';
    INSERT INTO #MyTempDataset SELECT 'test';

    DECLARE @counter INT
    DECLARE @word VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR
        FOR SELECT  *
            FROM    #MyTempDataset;
        OPEN myCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @word
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN               
            -- check for condition
            SELECT  @counter = Count(*) 
            FROM    #MyTempDataset
            WHERE   word = @word

            IF @counter =1
            BEGIN
                -- process the unique records
                PRINT @word     
            END     

            FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @word
        END
        CLOSE myCursor;
        DEALLOCATE myCursor;

    DROP TABLE #MyTempDataset;
```

Comment: @Almazini Sorry, I didn't see your code until after I posted mines.

Comment: Thanks for including "BEGIN" and "END" after the IF  :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer this question. But for the sake of other users seeking for a better answer. You can simply skip the record by calling the `FETCH NEXT`.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

IF @ParameterName = '@RETURN_VALUE' 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @procSchema INTO @ParameterName, @Type;

   .... Rest of the logic goes here
```

With this approach you don't have to wrap the whole logic in a If statement instead you'll move to the next one record skipping the current record.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use CONTINUE command to skip to the next iteration of a while loop.

```
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR INTO @PARAM
      IF @cond CONTINUE /* Skip */
      /* Do stuff */
    END
```

2. Use a Label: and a GOTO to continue execution from another place in the code

   ```
      BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR INTO @PARAM
      IF @cond GOTO: endOfCursorLabel
      /* Do stuff */
      endOfCursorLabel:
      END
   ```

Reference "Control-of-Flow" for more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-ver16