# How do a Skip a Row With SQL Cursor without a Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I have a large table in SQL with the following columns:

| CompanyId(int) | Email(Varchar 255) | First_Name(Varchar 50) | Last_Name(Varchar 50) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jim_halpert@dundermifflin.com | Jim | Halpert |
| 2 | bvance@vancerefridgerations.com | Bob | Vance |
| 1 | michael_scott@dundermifflin.com | Michael | Scott |

CompanyId can repeat several times as the companies are attached to various emails.

My employer wants me to find Company emails that belong to a specific type. After several IF statements, the end result would print a message like:

> "CompanyId" has firstName_lastName@companyName.domain type email
>
> "CompanyId" has firstInitial_lastName@companyName.domain type email

My employers told me to use Cursor to find my solution, but once I start my cursor I need to check the CompanyId to see if that id has already been looped and a type found. If the CompanyId has already gone through the cycle, I want to skip it.

This is my code thus far

```
      DECLARE @CoId INT
            ,@Email VARCHAR(255)
            ,@FName varchar(50)
            ,@LName varchar(50)
        Declare @condition bit = 1 
    
    Declare CoCursor CURSOR
    For SELECT E.CompanyID, E.Email, P.First_Name, P.Last_Name 
    From Table_Email as E
    Left Join Table_People as P
    ON E.EmployeeID = P.EmployeeID
    Order by CompanyID, Email
    
    -- Loop through the rows with Cursors for CompanyId and Email
    
    OPEN CoCursor
        Fetch NEXT FROM CoCursor
            INTO @CoId, @Email, @FName, @LName
    
        While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
            -- Check to see if CompanyId has been logged before, if not, proceed
                -- Check to see if email matches criteria
                IF @Email LIKE @FName + '[_]' + @LName + '@%'
                    BEGIN
                -- If yes, check next email where CompanyIds match
                    ;WITH EmailTable(CompanyID, Email, First_Name, Last_Name) AS (
                         SELECT E.CompanyID, E.Email, P.First_Name, P.Last_Name 
                         From Table_Emails as E
                         Left Table_People as P
                         ON E.EmployeeID = P.EmployeeID
                         Where E.CompanyID = @CoId 
                         And E.Email LIKE P.First_Name + '[_]' + P.Last_Name + '@%')
                    Select TOP(2) @condition = 0
                    FROM EmailTable         
                    Having COUNT(*) > 1
                    -- If email matches previous email, log Company Id with the email type
                    IF @condition = 0
                    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @CoId) + ' has email like firstName_lastName@CompanyAddress.domain' 
                -- If not, go to next Email check                           
                    END
                IF @Email LIKE LEFT(@FName,1) + @LName + '@%'
                -- If yes, check next email where CompanyIds match
                -- If email matches previous email, log Company Id with the email type
        -- If it has been logged move onto next record.
            Fetch NEXT FROM CoCursor
                INTO @CoId, @Email, @FName, @LName
        -- Once the result is logged go to next row 
            END         
    CLOSE CoCursor
    DEALLOCATE CoCursor
```

One solution I saw used a temp table to log ids that have been used before, but my employer doesn't want me using temp tables.
[How Can I Skip a row(an iteration) in MSSQL Cursor based on some condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294127/how-can-i-skip-a-rowan-iteration-in-mssql-cursor-based-on-some-condition/22294340)

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just put 1 row per company into the `CURSOR` in the first place? Though why you were told to you a `CURSOR` in the first place is beyond me.

Comment: `;WITH` The semi-colon is a statment **terminator**, not a "beginator". Use terminators for all your statements and you don't need this kludge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors are slow and inefficient, and are rarely needed.

**This doesn't need a cursor at all.** A simple filtered join with a `group by` will suffice

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(e.CompanyID), ' has email like firstName_lastName@CompanyAddress.domain')
FROM Table_Email e
JOIN Table_People p ON p.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
WHERE e.Email LIKE p.First_Name + '[_]' + p.Last_Name + '@%'
GROUP BY
  e.CompanyID
ORDER BY
  e.CompanyID;
```

---

Apparently, for some very strange reason, your employers have *mandated* a cursor, and I'm sure you will tell them all the reasons why not to use them. But here you go anyway:

Your original code is still very convoluted, and you can simplifiy it by using the code above as the `SELECT` for the cursor.

> Note the use of a local variable for the cursor, this means you don't have to deallocate it

```
DECLARE @CompanyID int;

DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;
SET @crsr = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
  e.CompanyID
FROM Table_Email e
JOIN Table_People p ON p.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
WHERE e.Email LIKE p.First_Name + '[_]' + p.Last_Name + '@%'
GROUP BY
  e.CompanyID
ORDER BY
  e.CompanyID;

OPEN @crsr;

FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr
  INTO @CompanyID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT CONCAT(e.CompanyID), ' has email like firstName_lastName@CompanyAddress.domain');

    FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr
      INTO @CompanyID;
END;

CLOSE @crsr;
```

Comment: As much as I would like to not use a cursor, my employers told me to.

Comment: Employers don't always know best, @morganherg . I often don't let my manager tell me how I should implement a requirement because I know SQL Server far better than they do. A good employee knows when to both question the intent and also reject it.

Comment: Otherwise we could always could to the age old analogy: If your employer told you the solution was to walk into traffic, would you, @morganherg ? (I hope not.)

Comment: Employer as in my senior developer. I'm still learning the ropes of advanced SQL queries and they wanted me to learn bit modularity using either while loops or cursors. As much as everyone's answers make sense, I'm stuck using cursors.

Comment: OK I've converted it for a cursor also. Modularity has nothing to do with while loops and cursors, and the *first* thing to understand about cursors is when or if to use them

Answer (score 1):

I do not like cursors too much, so I am going to propose another possible solution (I think it is a better one, although your employers want a cursor for some strange reason).

Your sample data:

```
create table Table_Email (
    CompanyID int, 
    EmployeeID int,
    Email varchar(255)
)

create table Table_People (
    CompanyID int, 
    EmployeeID int,
    First_Name varchar(50),
    Last_Name varchar(50),
)

insert into Table_Email values (1, 1, 'jim_halpert@dundermifflin.com')
insert into Table_Email values (2, 2, 'bvance@vancerefridgerations.com')
insert into Table_Email values (1, 3, 'michael_scott@dundermifflin.com')

insert into Table_People values (1, 1, 'Jim', 'Halpert')
insert into Table_People values (2, 2, 'Bob', 'Vance')
insert into Table_People values (1, 3, 'Michael', 'Scott')
```

My proposed query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CompanyID) + ' has email like firstName_lastName@CompanyAddress.domain' FROM 
(
 SELECT E.CompanyID, E.Email, P.First_Name, P.Last_Name 
 From Table_Email as E Left Join Table_People as P 
 ON E.EmployeeID = P.EmployeeID 
 WHERE Email LIKE P.First_Name + '[_]' + P.Last_Name + '@%' 
) AS a
group by CompanyID
order by CompanyID
```

It returns:

|  |
| --- |
| 1 has email like firstName_lastName@CompanyAddress.domain |

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c30e8/1

Answer (score 0):

Make CompanyId Distinct in the the Cursor

```
Declare CoCursor CURSOR
For Select CompanyID, 
            Email, 
            First_Name, 
            Last_Name
FROM (SELECT E.CompanyID, 
            E.Email, 
            P.First_Name, 
            P.Last_Name, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E.CompanyID ORDER BY E.Email ASC) as RN
From Table_Emails as E
Left Table_People as P
ON E.EmployeeID = P.EmployeeID) as T
Where RN = 1
Order by CompanyID
```